# ConsumerBuilder<Ignore, string>(conf).Build() works in Unity but "Sequence contains no matching element" error when deployed to Hololens

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, apache-kafka, hololens

The below C# code works great in the Unity Editor- it sets up Kafka and messages are logged as expected.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;
using UnityEngine;
using Confluent.Kafka;

public class main : MonoBehaviour
{
    ConsumerBuilder<Ignore, string> cb;
    IConsumer<Ignore, string> c;
    ConsumerConfig conf;
    CancellationTokenSource cts;

    int milliseconds = 10;
    TimeSpan timeout;

    void Start()
    {
        print("main start");
        conf = new ConsumerConfig();
        conf.GroupId = "test-consumer-group";
        conf.BootstrapServers = "localhost:9092";
        conf.AutoOffsetReset = AutoOffsetReset.Earliest;

        cb = new ConsumerBuilder<Ignore, string>(conf);
        if (cb != null)
        {
            print("cb is ok: " + cb.ToString());
            c = cb.Build();
        }

        timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, milliseconds);
        c.Subscribe("testTopicName");
        cts = new CancellationTokenSource();

        print("main started");
    }
```

However, when I build the Visual Studio solution and deploy to a Hololens, it throws an Exception:

```
Exception thrown at 0x776F3072 in MRB100.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: Il2CppExceptionWrapper at memory location 0x01F0BB84.
Exception thrown at 0x776F3072 in MRB100.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: Il2CppExceptionWrapper at memory location 0x01F0E384.
Exception thrown at 0x776F3072 in MRB100.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: Il2CppExceptionWrapper at memory location 0x01F0E384.
InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains no matching element
  at System.Linq.Enumerable.Single[TSource] (System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] source, System.Func`2[T,TResult] predicate) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at Confluent.Kafka.Impl.Librdkafka.SetDelegates (System.Type nativeMethodsClass) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at Confluent.Kafka.Impl.Librdkafka.Initialize (System.String userSpecifiedPath) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at Confluent.Kafka.Consumer`2[TKey,TValue]..ctor (Confluent.Kafka.ConsumerBuilder`2[TKey,TValue] builder) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at Confluent.Kafka.ConsumerBuilder`2[TKey,TValue].Build () [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at main.Start () [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 

(Filename: currently not available on il2cpp Line: -1)
```

If I disabled the line `c = cb.Build();` (and `c.Subscribe("testTopicName");`), the error goes away.

I'm new to C#/Unity/Hololens development and not sure what to make of this. I found several answers like
http://taswar.zeytinsoft.com/linq-sequence-contains-no-matching-element/

```
For example if you use
> var result = myEnumerableCollection.First(x => x.Name == person.Name);

This will throw InvalidOperationException with Sequence contains no matching element.
But if you use
> var result = myEnumerableCollection.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == person.Name);
> if(result == null) //did not find in the collection something went wrong or .....

Which will return you a null if its not found then you can check if the result is null and continue on with your work
```

but, as far as I can see, this scenario doesn't apply to my code.

I uploaded the Unity project 
https://github.com/BitterDone/MRB100/tree/master

and the VS-built project deployed to the Hololens (1.2 GB)
https://github.com/BitterDone/MRB100/tree/000-addBuiltProject

Any ideas or help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Not sure if i can help but seeing Unity3d + Kafka is too nice! I guess probably it is not connecting to the broker? Do you have kafka running inside hololens (`localhost:9092`)!? I would subscribe only if the consumer is created properly but in your code you just log if it is null. The other thing is that update is called every frame, too much i would say, while the `consumer.consume()` needs its time to get the records, I don't think setting a zero timeout is wise

Comment: Hi @Paizo, good thinking. 1. I'm not sure if Kafka can run in the Hololens, as it's only a Java server, but localhost probably needs to change to my laptop's IP, where I have Kafka running.  2. Do you mean that c.Subscribe("testTopicName") should run if(c != null)? 3. I found a 10ms timeout "works for now," at human speed. c.Consume(cts) blocks indefinitely until a message is received, which fooled me into thinking Unity was freezing. I definitely need to performance test the 10ms, though.

Comment: yes sure, if c is null you will get a null pointer on subscribe. Indeed I would not even consider kafka running on hololens. I would decouple the `consume` from unity `Update` or `FixedUpdate`, you don't want to freeze the frame to wait for the records; save the records in a list and then you can work on them in the fixedupdate if you aim to spawn a mesh for example.